# Using WSGEN to combine WSDLS and XSDS into 1 WSDL

Tags: jax-ws

So I am working on a project that had previously had a service definition. I augmented it to add my methods, however, now when I run the following...

```
"c:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsgen.bat" -verbose -keep -cp . com.me.service.ServiceClass -d c:\tmp\19 -wsdl
```

It generates 2 WSDLs and 4 XSDs. If I try just loading the ServiceClass.wsdl usng SOAP UI (In a folder by itself) it complains about missing the other WSDLs and XSD documents.

Is there a way I can just generate 1 WSDL file that houses all of this information?